# Getting error when working with

Tags: python-3.x, wmi

I am trying to run a code under Python 3.32 64Bit windows 7 , i keep getting following error below
any idea or suggestion how to work with WMI , i tried WMI from pypy but its related to same error
Please advice
Thanks

> ImportError: No module named 'win32com'

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')

#List all processes
processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')
for process in processes:
    print (process.Properties_('Name'))

    #Get a specific process
    p = WMI.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name="chrome.exe"')
    #view all possible properties
for prop in p[0].Properties_:
   print (prop)
   #print out PID
   print (p[0].Properties_('ProcessId').Value)
```

Comment: You do not seem to have installed win32com. Nevertheless you are running an 64 bit Python but win32com is for 32 bits. Here is that Problem, too. http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Problem-using-win32com-client-Dispatch-on-Win7-64bit-td1957248.html

Comment: Fixed it just downloaded Python for Windows extensions from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/?source=dlp

Comment: Solved the problem by downloading Python for Windows extensions from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/?source=dlp and keep using Python x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by downloading

> Python for Windows extensions

from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/?source=dlp) and keep using Python x64

Thanks All